# Leaving luggage in locker while travelling

Tags: luggage-storage, berlin

I will be visiting Berlin and then go to Iceland. After my Iceland trip, I will be coming back to Berlin for my return journey.

As I will be returning back to Berlin, I don't want to carry all my luggage to Iceland.

Are there any options to keep my luggage in locker and collect it after few days? And are they safe?

Comment: How long is your trip to Iceland? How long is your second stay in Berlin? Are you going to stay at a hotel before and after you go to Iceland? Possibly the same hotel?

Comment: My Iceland trip is for 5 days. After returning from Iceland, i will stay in Berlin for 2 more days. I am currently planning to stay at a Hostel and yes it will be same before and after.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Berlin Tegel, you can use the luggage storage there. [Here](http://www.berlin-airport.de/de/reisende-txl/am-flughafen/gepaeck/gepaeckaufbewahrung/index.php) you can find the fees, and it also says that the storage duration is not limited.

There are also lockers at the train stations (Berlin central station for example, where you also can store your luggage for a few days, though i couldn't find the maximum storage duration for that).

Comment: The train station ones get expensive quite quickly. Though some 20 or 30 Euros might still be preferable to actually carrying everything around and paying for the additional luggage on your flight ticket.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of main cities I have been to have locker services at public transportation hubs (airports, train stations, bus terminals). Berlin is no exception.

The ones that I used in Amsterdam, Berlin, Prague and Amsterdam seemed very safe to me, and I would expect nothing less than perfect service and safety from a main city in Germany. When possible, I would recommend using the services of a company that is operated by the country, rather than privately owned.

Here is some information on [this service in Berlin](https://www.berlin.de/en/tourism/travel-information/1738016-2862820-lockers-leftluggage-office.en.html).

It's worth to keep in mind that some hotels can store luggage, although I'm not sure whether this also applies to extended periods. If you're staying at a hotel, it may be worth to ask.

Comment: Check the information on the lockers. Some places have a maximum period. In that case the locker will be emptied after the set period and the contents stored in a different location. That will be awkward and can be costly depending on how they charge that.

Comment: I am wondering if you have really been to Berlin :) Luggage lockers are OK (I mean, it's a locker, nothing too fancy) but “nothing less than perfect service” isn't really part of the culture there.

Comment: @Relaxed yeah, not in hotels anyway. The Bahn ones are fine, and large hotels are too, but I would **never** leave my stuff in a hostel. As a matter of fact, I'd not even leave it in the locker outside on Alexanderplatz either. I go past that thing almost every day and I wonder how people can leave their stuff there next to that weird cocktail bar every time.

Comment: These lockers generally have a 72 hour time limit, making them unsuitable in this case...